# Using passed value as the name of a control sequence with pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys, key-value

I have the following family of options

```
\pgfkeys{
    /opts/.is family,
    /opts,
    name/.store in = \@@Style@Name,
    property/.code = {
        \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\csname @@Style@ \@@StyleName @Poperty \endcsname#1},
}
```

I want to create a global command `\@@Style@<value of the "name">@Property` and assign it the value of "property" if it is passed.

For example, the code `\pgfkeys{/opts, name = A, property = B}` should create a command `\@@Style@A@Propety` with the value `B`. How can I do that.

Minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{
    /opts/.is family,
    /opts,
    name/.store in = \@@Style@Name,
    property/.code = {
        \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\csname @@Style@ \@@StyleName @Poperty \endcsname#1},
}

\begin{document}

    \pgfkeys{/opts, name = A, property = B}
    
    \@@Style@A@Propety

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact syntax from the question is implemented below (see *With the syntax from the question*), but my suggestion would be to use a slightly different one, namely:

```latex
\pgfkeys{/myopts={A=foo, B={bar baz\\quux}}}
```

in order to set `\@@Style@A@Property` to `foo` and  `\@@Style@B@Property` to `bar baz\\quux` (thus two assignments in this example, but you can perform as many as you want with my code). Indeed, the syntax you asked for requires stateful code:

- one needs to remember that the property name has been set until we see the value, or that the value has been set until we see the name;
- one needs to specify what happens with dubious input like `\pgfkeys{/opts, name=foo, name=bar, property=whatever}` or `\pgfkeys{/opts, property=whatever}`, etc.

The syntax I propose can be implemented by defining the `/some dir/.unknown` handler, which is invoked by `pgfkeys` whenever an unknown key in `/some dir` is used.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % for \csgdef (syntactic sugar)

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /myopts/dir/.unknown/.code={%
    \csgdef{@@Style@\pgfkeyscurrentname @Property}{#1}%
  },
  /myopts/.code={\pgfkeys{/myopts/dir/.cd, #1}},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/myopts={A=foo, B={bar baz\\quux}}}

\makeatletter
\show\@@Style@A@Property % \@@Style@A@Property=macro:->foo.
\show\@@Style@B@Property % \@@Style@B@Property=macro:->bar baz\\quux.
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Regarding the code you posted, please note that

```latex
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\csname @@Style@ \@@StyleName @Property \endcsname#1}
```

should rather be something like this:

```latex
\expandafter\gdef\csname @@Style@\@@StyleName @Property\endcsname{#1}
```

(no need for the second `\expandafter` because it is `\csname` that needs to be expanded early here; beware of unwanted spaces; wrap the macro replacement text within curly braces).

## With the syntax from the question

Since the OP insists on having exactly the syntax from the question, namely `\pgfkeys{/opts, name = A, property = B}`, here it is. I don't recommend it, though (there might be good reasons but they haven't been revealed so far, AFAICT). The `name` must be given before the `property` (as in the question).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{etoolbox}  % for \csgdef (syntactic sugar)

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /opts/.is family,
  /opts/name/.store in=\@@My@PropName,
  /opts/property/.code={%
    \csgdef{@@Style@\@@My@PropName @Property}{#1}%
  },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/opts, name = A, property = B}

\makeatletter
\show\@@Style@A@Property % \@@Style@A@Property=macro:->B.
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am a little confused, I don't think that the code does what I asked for. The name of the created command should be `\@@Style@<value>@Prorerty`, not `\@@Style@<key>@Property`.

Comment: I simply did what I understood from the question. You said you wanted `\pgfkeys{/opts, name = A, property = B}` to store `B` in macro `\@@Style@A@Propety` (sic), and that is what I did with what I think is a better syntax. If you want a `<key>=<value>` assignment to define macro `\@@Style@<value>@Prorerty`, what is going to be stored inside this macro? The `<key>`? This is a simple matter of swapping things but would be unintuitive, IMHO.

Comment: I want to store value of `property` in the `\@@Style@<value of name>@Property`.

Comment: What is `property`? There is no such thing in `\pgfkeys{/myopts={key1=value1, key2=value2}} `.

Comment: `name` and `property` are the names of the keys. `A` and `B` are their values respectively.

Comment: Well, apparently you didn't read my answer. I explained that this `name=A, property=B` syntax is not very good, IMHO. I implemented a better syntax in which there are no such keywords. So, the request doesn't make sense, sorry.

Comment: I understood that you don't like the syntax, but unfortunately, your code doesn't do what I want.

Comment: See the end of the updated answer. I've added an example that implements the precise requested syntax.